# QGIS 3: Python doesn't find gdal module

Tags: qgis, python, gdal

Today I've been messing around with QGIS installations and I think I've accidentally caused a problem: QGIS is no longer able to execute the GDAL raster tool 'Fill no data' and other GDAL tools that use Python.

I am using Windows 10 and installed QGIS 3.10.1 from www.qgis.org using the standalone QGIS version. Later, I uninstalled that installation from my pc, and installed QGIS and GDAL and GRASS GIS using the OSGeo4W Network installer (also through www.qgis.org). Then I couldn't figure out how to remove the OSGeo4W installation, so I just deleted the folder 'OSGeo4W' on my C:\ drive. And then I installed the standalone QGIS version again.

At this point, whenever I try to execute the GDAL tool 'Fill no data' on a raster layer in QGIS, I get the following error. Other GDAL tools that use Python generate the same error.

```
2019-12-11T17:20:16     INFO    python3 -m gdal_fillnodata -md 10 -b 1 -of GTiff C:/Users/username/Downloads/ahn_ruw/M_32GZ2.TIF C:/Users/username/Downloads/ahn_fill/test.tif
2019-12-11T17:20:16     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10\bin\python3.exe: No module named gdal_fillnodata
```

What I think is happening is that my current QGIS installation is looking for a non-existent Python/GDAL installation in the old OSGeo4W folder. Or some other confusing with different installations of Python/GDAL. I think it is a Python problem.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500176/importerror-no-module-named-gdal) but that didn't work. I've also tried changing the system variable PATH in QGIS under Settings > System to the folder C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37 but that didn't work. It seems that the correct path (C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37) is already in the system variable PATH.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: Do the other GDAL commands work? Or is it only gdal_fillnodata?

Comment: Only the GDAL commands that use python3 give the error. So for example, gdal2xyz doesn't work either. So I guess it's a python3 problem. I'll update my post.

Comment: How is PYTHONPATH set? Is gdal_fillnodata.py present in any folder?
Try setting PYTHONPATH to the folder where htere is gdal_fillnodata.py.

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea thanks, that worked! Problem solved :-) gdal_nofilldata.py is present in the folder C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts. I added that folder to PATH and PYTHONPATH and now it works again.

Comment: The bug was reported to QGIS developers https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33386 and it should now be resolved updating "python3-gdal2" / "gdal2-python" packages to 2.4.3-2 version without the need of manually set the PYTHONPATH environomental variable.

Comment: Also the package python3-core has been updated to version 3.7.0-4 in order to fix the bug for QGIS versions (like 3.10.1 on Windows) that use GDAL 3.